# Multiple div refresh on different timings in jquery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to set up two div entries on a page that are refreshed from a database at different rates.

I'd like to have one div display random entries from the database every second, and below that, every 10 seconds a random entry is selected and has 500 points added to its score.

I can do the second (lottery_Winner):

```
<div id="lottery_Winner" class = "tableCenter">
  {% for entry in lottery_winner %}
    <li class = "lot"> <a> {{"WINNER"}}</a> </li>
    <li class = "lot"><a href="/entries/{{ entry.id }}/"> <span id="entry-text">{{ entry.text }}</span> <span id="score">{{ entry.score }}</span></a></li>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var currentid = {{entry.id}};
        var args = {'lotteryid':currentid};
        $.get("/lotteryWinner/", args).done(function(data) {
                $("#score").text(data);      
           });
       });
    </script>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>     

  <script>
   setTimeout(function() {
     $.ajax({      
         url: "",
         context: document.getElementById("lottery_Winner"),
         success: function(data){
            $("#lottery_Winner").html(data);
         }
     });
   }, 5000);  
  </script>
```

but when I do the first (lottery_Cycle), I get unexpected results - they both refresh the same time (undesired), there is a "ghost" element for one or both of the divs, and the lottery_cycle div entry can get the 500 points, the Winner and Cycle have the same entries and the page refresh cascades until it hangs periodically.

Here's the code I tried:

```
 <div id="lottery_Cycle" class = "tableCenter">
   {% for entry in lottery_winner %}
    <li class = "lot"> <a> {{"LOTTERY"}}</a> </li>
    <li><a href="/entries/{{ entry.id }}/"> <div class = "lot" style = "text-align: left";>{{ entry.text }}
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div style="float: right">{{ entry.score }}</div></a></li>
   {% endfor %}
  </div> 

 <div id="lottery_Winner" class = "tableCenter">
   {% for entry in lottery_winner %}
    <li class = "lot"> <a> {{"*** LOTTERY WINNER ***"}}</a> </li>
    <li class = "lot"><a href="/entries/{{ entry.id }}/"> <span id="entry-text">{{ entry.text }}</span> <span id="score">{{ entry.score }}</span></a></li>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {         
        var currentid = {{entry.id}};
        var args = {'lotteryid':currentid};
        $.get("/lotteryWinner/", args).done(function(data) {
                $("#score").text(data);     
           });
       });
    </script>
   {% endfor %}
  </div>     

  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({      
        url: "",
        context: document.getElementById("lottery_Winner"),
        success: function(data){
         $("#lottery_Winner").html(data);
        }
      });
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({      
        url: "",
        context: document.getElementById("lottery_Cycle"),
        success: function(data){
         $("#lottery_Cycle").html(data);
        }
      });
    }, 1000);  
  </script>
```

and here is relevant part of views.py;

```
def lottery(request): 
  context = {
    'lottery_cycle': Entry.objects.random(),
    'lottery_winner': Entry.objects.random(),
  }
  return render(request, 'entries/lottery.html', context);

def lotteryCycle(request):
  c = Entry.objects.random()[0]
  return HttpResponse("%s,%s,%s" % (c.id, c.text, c.score))

def lotteryWinner(request):
  lottery_id = request.GET.get('lotteryid')
  if request.method=='GET':
     l = Entry.objects.get(pk=lottery_id)
     l.score +=500
     l.save()
     return HttpResponse(l.score)
  else:
     pass
  return HttpResponse('done')
```

(I tried setInterval as well as setTimeout, same result) Is there any advice on getting the two div refreshes working properly on different timings?

Comment: For `every X seconds` you don't need `setTimeout()`, you need `setInterval()`. And keep request-times in mind!

Comment: Thanks, I did try that as well, same result :(

Comment: Instead of `setInterval()` you should consider about calling the function itself in the ajax-callback (after loading process call a `setTimeout()`, new idea from me ;) ). But you could try to invoke the interval in your `$(document).ready(function() {})`, because then they will be called very close after each other... Maybe another problem is your `context` - try this `context: $("#lottery_Winner")` and then in your callback `$(this).html(data)` as described here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thank you. I did try the interval after the document ready function some time ago. Not much luck, but maybe I will have another go. Thanks for the advice, I will try some of those ideas.